# how to override views field template for all themes?

Tags: views, theming

I am aware you can add you a custom template for a views field such as `views-view-field--title.html.twig` to your theme. But this has a limitation that it only work for the active theme. Sometimes the admin theme is used out of the box and not as a sub theme. I am trying to figure out if I can force views to use a template of my choosing anywhere it appears regardless of the active theme.